# Merge regression results back to original dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, regression, pandas-groupby

I am working on a simple time series linear regression using statsmodels.api.OLS, and am running these regressions on groups of data based on an identifier variable. I have been able to get the grouped regressions working, but am now looking to merge the results of the regressions back into the original dataframe and am getting index errors.

A simplified version of my original dataframe, which we'll call "df" looks like this:

```
id    value    time
a      1        1
a      1.5      2
a      2        3
a      2.5      4
b      1        1
b      1.5      2
b      2        3
b      2.5      4
```

My function to conduct the regressions is as follows:

```
def ols_reg(df, xcol, ycol):
   x = df[xcol]
   y = df[ycol]
   x = sm.add_constant(x)
   model = sm.OLS(y, x, missing='drop').fit()
   predictions = model.predict()
   return pd.Series(predictions)
```

I then define a variable that stores the results of conducting this function on my dataset, grouping by the id column. This code is as follows:

```
var = df.groupby('id').apply(ols_reg, 
    xcol='time',ycol='value')
```

This returns a Series of the predicted linear values that has the same length as the original dataset, and looks like the following:

```
id
a   0  0.5
    1  1
    2  2.5
    3  3
b   0  0.5
    1  1
    2  2.5
    3  3
```

The column starting with 0.5 (ignore the values; not the actual output) is the column with predicted values from the regression. As the return on the function shows, this is a pandas Series.

I now want to merge these results back into the original dataframe, to look like the following:

```
id    value    time   results
a      1        1      0.5
a      1.5      2       1
a      2        3      2.5
a      2.5      4       3
b      1        1      0.5
b      1.5      2       1
b      2        3      2.5
b      2.5      4       3
```

I've tried a number of methods, such as setting a new column in the original dataset equal to the series, but get the following error:

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Any help on getting these results back into the original dataframe would be greatly appreciated. There are a number of other posts that correspond to this topic, but none of the solutions worked for me in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I've solved this with a relatively simple method, in which I converted the series to a list, and just set a new column in the dataframe equal to the list. However, I would be really curious to hear if others have better/different/unique solutions to this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To not loose the position when inserting prediction in the missing values you can use this approach, in example:

- X_train: The train data is a pandas dataframe corresponding to the known real results (in y_train).
- X_test: The test data is a pandas dataframe without corresponding known real results. Need to predict.
- y_train: The train data is pandas serie with real known results
- Prediction: The prediction is a pandas series object

To get the complete data merged in one pandas dataframe first get the known part together:

```
# merge train part of the data into a dataframe    
X_train = X_train.sort_index()
    y_train = y_train.sort_index()
    result = pd.concat([X_train,X_test])

# if need to convert numpy array to pandas series: 
# prediction = pd.Series(prediction)


# here is the magic
result['specie'][result['specie'].isnull()] = prediction.values
```

If there is no missing value would do the job.